# Get the name of the Application that triggers a call from WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

Is it possible to get the name of the Application that triggered the API call on WSO2 API Manager and pass it on to the call as a header?

Any can help how to do this please.

Comment: What do you mean by application? You mean client application which call an API in WSO2 API Manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, application name is part of the JWT token that you get with the calls. [Here's documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM191/Passing+Enduser+Attributes+to+the+Backend+Using+JWT).

JWT tokens are enabled by default in [WSO2 API Cloud](http://wso2.com/cloud/api-cloud) (the public hosted service from WSO2). So if you are using it - everything just works.

If you are deploying API Manager yourself, you need to configure JWT yourself as explained [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM191/Passing+Enduser+Attributes+to+the+Backend+Using+JWT).

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to implement an custom handler. See [Writing Custom Handlers](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Writing+Custom+Handlers)

APIMgtUsageHandler is one of the handlers in API manager which collects the application name (to collect usage data). So you can refer it as a sample handler on how to get the application name. see [APIMgtUsageHandler.java](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/master/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/usage/publisher/APIMgtUsageHandler.java)